# Jinja Troubles - info not portrayed

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to code some jinja into my html file and pull data from `MySQL` db.

My goal is to make it so after login, my home page says `welcome, (name)`.

I'm using a jinja for loop and if statement to pair user.id to my session_id. I have provided an image of my nav bar indicated with the red arrow where i want the welcome text to be. I provided the html for the nav bar, the python controller and model files.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJpQ9.png)

```
    <div class="nav">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/imgs/galaxygameslogo.png') }}" class="brand-logo" alt="" style="width: 399px;">
        <div class="nav-items">
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="search system, product">
                <button class="search-btn">search</button>
            </div>
            {% for user in users %}
            <div>
            {% if users.user_id == session['user_id'] %}
                <p>Welcome,{{ user.first_name }} </p>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <a href="/signin"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/imgs/user.png') }}" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/imgs/cart.png') }}" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Python Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcpvb.png)

```
#GET BY USER EMAIL
    @classmethod
    def get_by_email(cls, data):
        query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %(email)s;"
        result = connectToMySQL(db).query_db(query, data)
        if result:
            return cls(result[0])
        return False
```

[Python controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avTJh.png)

```
#SIGN IN POST
@app.route('/signin/user', methods=['POST'])
def signin_user():
    from flask_app.models.user import User
    user = User.get_by_email(request.form)
    if not user:
        flash("Invalid email or password", "login")
        return redirect('/signin')
    if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, request.form['password']):
        flash("Invalid password", "login")
        return redirect('/signin')
    session['user_id'] = user.id
    return redirect('/')
```

I've tried to verify the paths in the loop with the controller and match names of my tables from the databases. Also repositioning the loop.